# MSON specifying a date-time

Tags: jsonschema, apiblueprint, apiary.io, apiary, mson

How can the following MSON output a schema with "format":"date-time", similar to the stated below?

Mson:

```
FORMAT: 1A
# Some API

## series [/api/v1/series]

Returns a list of  series.

### View all series [GET]

+ Response 200 (application/json; charset=utf-8)
    + Attributes
        + CreatedAt (required, string)
```

Obtained Json Schema:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "CreatedAt": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "CreatedAt"
  ],
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#"
}
```

Desired Schema (Note the "format" field):

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "CreatedAt": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "date-time"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "CreatedAt"
  ],
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK unfortunately there is no way to specify some format on string fields yet.